# Extracting the Revision number of a file from the SVN Command line

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Hello 
Basically i need to extract the version info from the XML
I thought of puttin the entire result to a XML file and then 
parse it to get the revision information.

i tried to output the svn info to a xml file by specifying

```
$ svn info C:\Projects\Foo.xml --xml C:\Projects\FileInfo.xml
```

**Im getting errors if i try to save**

```
$ svn info --xml C:\Projects\Foo.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<entry
   kind="dir"
   path="."
   revision="1">
<url>https://rbins.com/trunk/Projects/Foo.xml</url>
<repository>
<root>https://rbins.com/trunk/Projects/</root>
<uuid>5e7d134a-54fb-0310-bd04-b611643e5c25</uuid>
</repository>
<wc-info>
<schedule>normal</schedule>
<depth>infinity</depth>
</wc-info>
<commit
   revision="240">
<author>sally</author>
<date>2003-01-15T23:35:12.847647Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>
```

**i do not receive error if i run**

$ svn info C:\Projects\Foo.xml --xml

Help me where am i going wrong also suggest me if theres any alternative available to extract the revision number of the working copy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **redirect** `svn info`'s output to the file, the `--xml` option takes no parameter:

> svn info C:\Projects\Foo.xml --xml
>   **>** C:\Projects\FileInfo.xml

Answer (score 5):

Use [`svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) instead:

```
>C:\mydir>svnversion
1652:1653
```

Comment: Hello Jason 
I need the version info for a particular file and not the revision of all the files in the directory of working copy